# vscode plt.show() no image displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

This is a simple example, I have searched and tried some methods, but no effect, I guess it may be my vscode settings or matplotlib package problems, expect to get some possible solutions

```
# Creating Test DataSets using sklearn.datasets.make_moon
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from matplotlib import style


X, y = make_moons(n_samples = 1000, noise = 0.1)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s = 40, color ='g')
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

plt.show()
```

Comment: I can not replicate your problem. Maybe uninstall and reinstall both `sklearn` and `matplotlib`. I get a scatter plot with two green spirals converging to the center.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any error report?

Comment: no any error report

Comment: There is no problem with your code. It works well in my vscode. Have you ever tried to run files in cmd of windows